# Android + NodeJS: Client-Server communication

Tags: android, node.js, client-server

I have some questions about developing a Android application which shall be able to communicate with a NodeJS server.

The Android application gathers some data and saves everything in a .csv file.
This file now needs to be uploaded to a NodeJS server. The NodeJS server should save the file as well as storing the content in a MongoDB.

My question now is how I should implement the communication between the Android device and the server.

I know how to upload a single file to a NodeJS server using a HttpURLConnection with a DataOutputStream.
But I need more than just uploading the file because I need a unique identification of each Android device.

I thought about using the (encrypted) Google account E-Mail address of the user to distinguish the devices. I am not interested in knowing who uploads which data but I need to store the data for each device separately.

The problem is that I don't know how to communicate between the device and the server.
If I upload a file via HttpURLConnection and DataOutptStream it seems that I can only upload the file without any additional information like the unique key for the device.

I also thought about uploading the file via sockets. But I am not sure how to handle huge file sizes (5 MB or more).

I am not looking for code fragments. I rather need some hints to the right direction. Hopefully my problem was stated clearly and someone can help me with this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using a HttpUrlConnection on the Android side, and a RESTful server on the Node side would be a straightforward option.

You can embed information into the URL in a RESTful way:

- pathParam: www.address.com/api/save/{clientId}/data
- queryParam: www.address.com/api/save/data?c={clientID}

each uniquely identifying the client. This can be whatever scheme you choose. You will have to build the HttpUrlConnection each time as the URI is unique, and important!

The server side can then route the URL however you see fit. Node has a number of packages to aid in that (Express, Restify, etc.). Basically you'll grab the body of the request to store into your DB, but the other parameters are available too so it's all a unique and separated transaction.

Edit: The package you use for RESTful handling can stream large files for you as well. Processing of the request can really begin once the data is fully uploaded to the server.

Comment: Thank you very much for this answer. Sounds to me like a good way to implement it.

Answer (score 1):

Using a socket would be nearly just as easy. The most difficult part will be 'making your own protocol' which in reality could be very simple.

Upload 1 file at at time by sending data to the socket like this:

```
54::{filename:'myfilename.txt',length:13023,hash:'ss23vd'}xxxxxxxxxxx...
```

`54`= length of the JSON txt
`::` = the delimiter between the length and the JSON
`{JSON}` = additional data you need
`xxx...` = 13023 bytes of data

Then once all the data is sent you can disconnect... OR if you need to send another file, you know where the next set of data should be.

And since node.js is javascript you already have wonderful JSON support to parse the JSON for you.

---

Would I suggest using a socket? Probably not. Because if you ever have to upload additional files at the same time, HTTP and node.js HTTP modules might do a better job. But if you can guarantee nothing will ever change, then sure, why not... But that's a bad attitude to have towards development.

Comment: Thanks for this answer. I also had the feeling that doing this with sockets would be kinda wrong. I will try to implement it the way Clay wrote in his answer.